# What is the most comfortable/conventional way to modify a specific item in an array, in a React component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I often find my self struggling with manipulating a specific item in an array, in a React component state. For example:

```
state={
menus:[
  {
    id:1,
    title: 'something',
    'subtitle': 'another something',
    switchOn: false
  },
  {
    id:2,
    title: 'something else',
    'subtitle': 'another something else',
    switchOn: false
  },
 ]
}
```

This array is filled with objects, that have various properties. One of those properties is of course a unique ID. This is what i have done recentely to edit a "switchOn" property on an item, according to its ID:

```
handleSwitchChange = (id) => {

  const newMenusArray = this.state.menus.map((menu) => {    
    if (menu.id === id) {
      return {
        ...menu,
        switchOn: !menu.switchOn
      };
    } else {
      return menu;
    };
  })
  this.setState(()=>{
    return{
      menus: newMenusArray
    }
  })   

}
```

As you can see, alot of trouble, just to change one value. In AngularJS(1), i would just use the fact that objects are passed by reference, and would directly mutate it, without any ES6 hustle.

Is it possible i'm missing something, and there is a much more straightforward approach for dealing with this? Any example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can do it in one line using this, but you are right this is too much comparing to mutating the references in other libraries,
`handleSwitchChange = (id) => {this.setState({menus: this.state.menus.map(menu=>(menu.id===id ? {...menu: switch: !menu.switch} : menu))}`

Comment: Well, it seems basically the same, but shorter :D

Comment: I agree with @Luke that it's better to re-arrange your state so that it's easier to manipulate. Nevertheless, if you're manipulating this kind of structure I think the easiest way is to use libraries like lodash or ramda. Are you open to that or are you looking for a vanilla js solution?

Comment: I'm totally open to that :D

Comment: @sheff2k1 look a lenses, IIRC the ramda implementation is pretty reasonable. But yeah, second the others that your state looks... uncommon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way is to make yourself a indexed map. Like you might know it from databases, they do not iterate over all entries, but are using indexes. Indexes are just a way of saying ID A points to Object Where ID is A

So what I am doing is, building a indexed map with e.g. a reducer

```
const map = data.reduce((map, item) => {
    map[item.id] = item;
    return map;
}, {})
```

now you can access your item by ID simply by saying

```
map[myId]
```

If you want to change it, you can use than object assign, or the `...` syntax

```
return {
    // copy all map if you want it to be immutable
    ...map
    // override your object
    [id]: {
        // copy it first
        ...map[id],
        // override what you want
        switchOn: !map[id].switchOn
    }
}
```

As an helper library, I could suggest you use [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), where you just change the value as it were a reference

Comment: Yeah, i did it few times with Lodash .mapKeys() method. It's nice, but requires me to use Object.keys in the JSX, being that ES5 map() function doesn't support objects

Comment: maybe a Object.values would help. Although it requires a polyfill sometimes, hat troubles to make it work once in the past. But you know, it is also the best way to work with keys, also in lets say redux. you will have a lot less troubles

Comment: I can try the Object.values, i would assume that Babel takes care of the polyfill

Comment: look at my updated anwser, maybe you can make use of immutable js, which helps a lot if you are having hard times get along with immutablity and this unncommon boilerplatish code

Comment: About the immutable.js: Can i just use it directly on the React state, without setState, or what?

Comment: nope. you have to call setState no matter what. But just one more hint, why immutablilty will be always better than references: It is super fast. just imagine you change one object, angular has to do a lot more. in react it is just saying oldObj === newObj and it will be false. in reference you always have to find where the change is. I know, it´s can be hard at the beginning. And if you come from angular it is like wtf at the beginning.

Comment: one thing: setState state no matter what is quite wrong. You should rearrange the data before you are in the component. And then pass the rearranged data into the component via props. I would not rearrange data in the component, i guess. your data should be normalized the same way everywhere.

Comment: Ah, so you're suggesting i should create the dictionary on my API?

Comment: i suggest do it once, so that it is consistent everywhere. I often cannot control what the API gives me. So mostly a define the structure where my data is stored. when you use redux, it is of course right after you fetched it, in the global store.

Comment: Well, i created my own API with php, so i could change it there...Thanx for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `findIndex`

```
handleSwitchChange = (id) => {
  var index = this.state.menu.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.id === id;
  });

  if (index === -1) {
    return;
  }

  let newMenu = this.state.menu.slice();
  newMenu[index].switchOn = !this.state.menu[index].switchOn;

  this.setState({
    menu: newMenu
  });
}
```

Comment: Interesting, i wasn't even aware of the existence of that method :D